# Trouble translating pseudo-code into Scala

Tags: java, python, arrays, scala, dictionary

I am trying to make my Scala code like my pseudo-code. I can easily convert my pseudo-code to Python code and get the values I want. But, my Scala code is giving all kinds of errors. How can I make my Scala code perform the same way as my pseudo-code?

Pseudo-code:

```
#def word(file, first_word, second_word):
#     -open file and read the file
#     -create a hash table called table_1
#     -create a hash table called table_2
#     -create a hash table called table_3
#     -create a empty string called string_1
#     -create a empty string called string_2
#     -loop through file line by line
#     -take every first word of each line as key and concatenate the
#      pronunciations of each line as value and store this in 
#       table_1
#     -loop through the keys and values in table_1
#     -loop through the values of table_1 and add only the values 
#      to string_1 that are not numeric values; this new string 
#      will now be the value of table_2 with the key still remaining 
#      as the word
#     -loop through the keys and values in table_2
#     -now take the string values of table_2 and reverse that 
#      backwards
#     -loop through the reversed string and keep adding the 
#      values to string_2 until you encounter a vowel.
#     -now you add this new string to table_3 as values with 
#      the same words as before as keys 
#     -if first_word is not in table_3 or second_word is not in 
#      table_3, then return an empty list
#     -if the values of first_word and the values of second_word 
#      are equal; then return True, meaning that the words rhyme
#    -if the values of first_word and the values of second_word 
#     are not equal; then return False, meaning that the words 
#     don't rhyme
```

Comment: How set are you on that pseudocode? If you follow those instructions, it won't really look like good scala code.

Comment: What would be considered good scala code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a bit broad at the moment and notable doesn't include information about the specific errors you are encountered with the Scala code you're writing. It may be helpful to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54677971/edit) your question to provide additional detail or narrow the focus to some of the specific issues you're running into.

Comment: Literally everything about the Scala code is bugged.

Comment: Anyone who produced Scala code matching that pseudo-code would not get a passing grade from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a scala version of the pseudo code. It doesn't match the pseudo code exactly but maybe it gives some useful hints

```
val source = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines

// take every first word of each line as key and concatenate the
// pronunciations of each line as value and store this in table_1

val table1: Map[String, String] = source.map { line => 
                                                  val words = line.split(" ")
                                                  (words.head, words.drop(1).mkString)
                                              }
                                        .toMap

// loop through the values of table_1 and add only the values 
// to string_1 that are not numeric values; this new string 
// will now be the value of table_2 with the key still remaining 
// as the word

val table2 = table1.map { case (key, value) => 
                              val string_1 = value.toCharArray
                                                  .filter(!_.isDigit)
                                                  .mkString
                              (key, string_1)
                        }
                    .toMap

// -loop through the reversed string and keep adding the 
// values to string_2 until you encounter a vowel.
// -now you add this new string to table_3 as values with 
//the same words as before as keys

val table3 = table2.map { case (key, value) =>
                              val string_2 = value
                                           .reverse
                                           .takeWhile("AEIOU".indexOf(_) == -1)
                              (key, string_2 + value.charAt(value.length - 1 - string_2.length))
                        }
                  .toMap

val first_word = "CAT"
val second_word = "xx"

if (table3.get(first_word).isDefined && table3.get(second_word).isDefined) {

    Left(table3.get(first_word).get == table3.get(second_word).get)

} else {

    Right(List())
}
```

Comment: How would I open the file and read them because the actual file has thousands of lines?

Comment: I've updated the code, instead of having a `List[String]` as source, initialise the `source` val with `Source.fromFile(filename).getLines`

Comment: For the last line 'res1==res2' , if I were to want to use that in a method to return either true or false, do I still use printIn?

Comment: if memory is a concern then use `view` which makes everything lazy, something like this `Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.view`

Comment: Would you say that the only module that I would import is 'import scala.io.Source'?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. If you use an IDE like Scala IDE for Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea just use the shortcuts for import Ctrl+Shift+O for Eclipse or Alt+Enter for Idea

Comment: Final question: "if first_word is not in table_3 or second_word is not in 
 table_3, then return an empty list", how would you implement that correctly in Scala?

Comment: That part of the pseudo code is a bit confusing for me, because if one of the words does not have values in table3 the method should return a `List`, while if both words have values in table3 the method should return a `Boolean`. It's a bit odd but it can be implemented in scala using [Either type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html)

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of Either type for returning the value

Comment: Basically if either words can't be found in the file, then an empty list will be returned because the word does not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your last comment. Either type is a type encapsulating two types. In the case described by pseudo code it is `Either[Boolean, List]` which means the method returns a `Left` encapsulating a `Boolean` or a `Right` encapsulating a `List`

Comment: @Anonymous; Returning `true` or `false` or `Array()` is a little like sending candy or flowers or a dead cat. Surely there are better ways to signal that no candy/flowers could be sent.

Comment: This is a bit late, but table3 should also include the last vowel, not just the last letter.

Comment: I've updated the answer, a solution would be to get the first encountered vowel and append it to the string of consonants just built `(key, string_2 + value.charAt(value.length - 1 - string_2.length))`